Reference request for different network types
I am trying to understand the mathematical models used in airline revenue management when a disruption occurs. The researchers are re-scheduling the resources(aircraft, flights etc.) in recovery process while minimizing the total disruption cost. They are using different types of network such as:

Time-Connection
Time-Band
Time-Line

After giving (MILP/MINLP) mathematical model, they solve it using column generation/Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition or using (Meta)-Heuristics.
What are some references (articles/books etc.) to understand these concepts based on networks?

You can try looking up some of the work by Cynthia Barnhart in this space. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054811001808
